# Uneven border spacing

Tags: html, css

I'm fiddling with the basic css box model to see how it works, but I'm already getting some weird results.

Here's the code:

```css
html {
  background-color: brown;
}

div {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>div 1</div>
<div>div 2</div>
<div>div 3</div>
<div>div 4</div>
<div>div 5</div>
<div>div 6</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why does the first and last spacing between divs' borders have 3 pixels, while the others have 4 pixels? I'm opening the html file with Chrome.

Edit: about how I'm noticing the difference in size: they look different to me, so I took a screenshot and counted the pixels on Paint. If this is not a reliable method, please let me know.

Comment: All the gaps look the same size on my computer, both in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: @BrettDonald I'm gonna test it in other computers then, but if the problem is my computer, what can be the problem?

Comment: If your computer is not a Mac, there’s the problem.

Comment: @BrettDonald Can you elaborate?

Answer (score -2):

`display: block` only expands to it's parent's or child's width.
To fit the child's height you need to set a height or add some display that respect these dimensions.

I like to use `grid` and/or `flex` display because of its ease, so you can do somenthing like this:

```
<body>
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
  <div>div 3</div>
  <div>div 4</div>
  <div class="a">div 5</div>
  <div class="b">div 6</div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
html {
  background-color: brown;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  gap: 3px; // gap between divs
  padding: 3px; // padding of entire body
}

div {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 3px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  //margin: 10px;
}

.a {
  padding: 20px;
}

.b {
  padding: 15px;
}
```

Comment: I'll probably end up using grid layout and/or flexbox, but I was trying to understand how the default layout works. I don't think I understand your answer.. why does the spacing between the divs varies in my example? Since they all have the same styles, shoudn't they have the same spacings between them?

Comment: @GuilhermeD'Osualdo I forgot to say: the default display for `body` tag is `block`. This will make you understand.

Comment: [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.php) you can see the default values of HTML elements.

Comment: Yes, I know that the display value is block by default, but that still doesn't answer the uneven spacing.